# Scilab multiple functons

Tags: scilab

I am working with scilab 5.4.1. Is there any way to define and invoke more than 1 function in .sci file. I have read in theory that there is a possibility. Does somebody know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, just define multiple functions in one file.

```
//First function
function x=myfct(a, b)
  x=a+b
endfunction

//Second function
function y=myfct2(a, b)
  y=a/b
endfunction

//Third function
function y=myfct3(a, b, c)
   y = myfct(a,b)
   y = myfct2(y,c)
   disp(y)
endfunction
```

See [the SciLab help pages](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.1/en_US/functions.html) for more information about functions.

After defining the above functions in a file and running the file once, the files are defined. You can now call them from console:

```
>> myfct3(3,4)
```

Comment: Thankyu so much. I am new to scilab. I tried this and yes it worked but in this case i will have to pass the values of parameters(a,b) n scinotes or pass values for the two functions independently in console but is it possible to get user defined values calculated for both at same stage.

Comment: You mean calling functions from console?

Comment: Yes is it possible i call both at same time, in same line.. Infact i'll be putting up 6-7 different functions

Comment: Make a function calling the other functions. See for instance third function in my answer